# Why is my site removing $_GET and hyphenating my search term?

Tags: search

I'm working on a WordPress site whose search is not working. If I try to search for "health data", the search term becomes "health-data" which is unlikely to find anything.
I'm using search.php and searchform.php as per WordPress documentation. As a side note, if I put a breakpoint in the first line of /index.php, there is no $_GET object at all.

However, if I create a test.html page at https://sitename/test.html with that exact same form html in it, there is a $_GET parameter for "s" and the search term is "health data" which finds several results.

I've been racking my brain trying to find out what may be causing this. I've turned off most of the plugins and have commented-out most of the functions.php file but it's still hyphenating the search term on the "normal" search page.

If anyone seeing this has any ideas I'm all open. What else might I try to try to uncover what may be happening?

WordPress version: 6.0 (but another site I have on this same version works just fine)

Comment: 6.0 is quite old, but you should be able to dump `$_GET` and see results in `index.php`, this heavily implies an Nginx/Apache level configuration error or a security mechanism is interfering Hyphenating is also not normal WordPress behaviour for a search term and also implies a redirect ( which wouldn't be possible if `GET` was blank as it wouldn't know what the term was ). WP 6.0 is also _very_ old. When yo say the search term becomes `health-data`, _where_ does that happen? Can you be specific? Avoid descriptions and use hard data and concrete examples where possible